# How can I hide result of evaluation in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

example:
Array = Range[1000]

I'll see 1000 numbers. Could I hide this output?

In Maple this problem solve by adding a ":" at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Array = Range[1000];
```

The ";" hides the results in Mma.

HTH!

Comment: @mike Mathematica docs are not easy to navigate at first. I suggest you reading some book and/or watching some videos to catch the wave

Answer (score 9):

First, in Mathematica you should not use capitalized variable names. The value "Array" is a built in function and Mathematica will not let you assign a value to it.

The answers above are completely correct, but there is another answer which some people might like. The Mathematica front end reformats output that it thinks might be hard to read. For example,

array = Range[100000]

will not print a giant list but instead will print:

"A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it:"

It will then show only the beginning and end of the list with an ellipsis of sorts. Try it out. You will find 4 buttons beneath the output reading:

"Show Less", "Show More", "Show Full Output", "Set Size Limit..."

Their meaning is pretty clear. You can change Mathematica's option which tells it at what size to consider the output too big to put on the screen.

You can find this option by clicking on "Set Size Limit" or by going to the Evaluation Tab in the Preferences menu. The Preferences menu is found under Edit>Preferences or Mathematica>Preferences if you are using a Mac. In this dialog you will find a field called "Maximum output size before truncation". Here you can specify the number of bytes Mathematica can put on the screen before it should truncate your input for easier use.

Comment: +1 Good eye on the uppercase usage. BTW, note that however Mma will not render the full output, it will format it, and that may take A LOT of time for big lists. It's always better to print just what you want.

Answer (score 2):

End the command in a `;` like so:

```
Array = Range[1000];
```

Useful links:

- [The Mathematica help page on `;`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html)

Answer (score 1):

you put a semicolon at the end. (eg: ar=Range[1000];)